# sign in with apple - firebase auth, providerData is null

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic4, apple-sign-in

I am working on ionic 4. I have configured Firebase and sign in with apple for web.

This is how I am using,

```js
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('apple.com');
provider.addScope('email');
provider.addScope('name');
const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
```

But for some reason  **email**, **name** and all the **providerData** is null.

I have followed [this](https://fireship.io/lessons/apple-signin-with-firebase-tutorial/).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Am struggling with the same issue. Did you resolve it?